# How to blur ImageData in different coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, game-engine, slot

I am studying HTML5 and building my slot game from scratch. when spinning, i want to implement a blur in Y to imageData. I try some algrothim already to imageData, it makes everything become very slow, and i try webkitFilter for canvas's style as well, it is only available for radius. Do you have any good suggestions for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-render your motion blurred slot spinning wheel:

- Start with an image that has all the slot elements arranged vertically.
- Create vertical motion blur using a temporary canvas (see code below).
- To "spin", animate the taller wheel canvas through the slot window.

[image]

To efficiently create vertical motion blur:

- Repeatedly drawing the vertical slot image.
- Increase the Y-offset with each draw.
- Decrease the opacity with each draw.

This is the y-blur code:

```
function motionBlur(wheelContext, image, blurAmount) {
    wheelContext.clearRect(0,0,wheelContext.canvas.width,wheelContext.canvas.height)
    var y=0;
    while (++y <= blurAmount) {
        wheelContext.globalAlpha=1/y;
        wheelContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height+y);
    }
}
```